# User registration through admin login using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

my requirement is to create user accounts through admin login. I have installed cancan,devise and rollify but problem is i'm unable to trace how to do. Please help me out.I have to register users by admin login.

Comment: Got any more context? Have you implemented normal user accounts yet, or not?

Comment: Create a controller called admin as you have described and then create all the devise view by devise commands and make changes into routes file.

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need is at this link:

[Adding an Admin Role](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-an-Admin-role)

When you deploy your application, you can then use the console to create your first Admin, who can in turn create Users via the GUI as per normal in a CRUD Rails application. Make sure that in your Users controller you have a `before_filter` that checks for `admin_signed_in?` on the create action (assuming that you have called your Admin role 'Admin' when creating it using `rails generate devise Admin` on the command line) - this will make sure that only Admins can access the `create` action in the Users controller. You could also wall off the `edit` and `destroy` actions in the same way, but I'm guessing you'd want to allow a User access to those.